# How not to preview photo after taking it?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I am using camera2basic android sample for my application. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java). What I want to get rid of is the short preview of photo that has just been taken. So I want the application to take photo, save it on device, and not display it after that. How can I disable this?

Comment: There is nothing in the code that show a kind of short preview. I think it is part of your phone. Like is it the same "short preview" in the app than in your photo application ? if it is the case then you can't disable it, sorry

Comment: @ArnauldAlex Well, it is kind of similar, but I am not sure. The problem is that I am developing a timelapse app, and I can't take pictures fast enough with that preview. But the other timelapse app I downloaded takes pictures without any preview, the same as recording a video, and is capable of taking photos much faster that I am.

Comment: https://lorentzos.com/making-pictures-capture-in-android-simple-74416a19e800 Or even this https://android.jlelse.eu/the-least-you-can-do-with-camera2-api-2971c8c81b8b 

I don't know this but it look great. Don't bother you with all the stuff of size ect like in camera2basic ! so much thing useless in it. try to start from somewhere else. By the way I understand your problem and think that you should start without camera2basic. camera and android is quite hard. Well, hope I helped you !